# How to set a value to select box from the database which value will load on 'change' event of another select box in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have Countries(id,country) and states(id,country_id,state) models 
countries hasmany states

In countries controller

In html

```
<li><?php echo $form->input('bcountry', array('empty' => 'Select Country', 'options' => $countries, 'id' => 'bco', 'label'=>'Country')); ?></li>
<li><div id="msg7"></div></li>
<li><div class="ajax_loading_image"></div></li>
<li><?php echo $form->input('bstate', array('type' => 'select', 'empty' => 'Select State','id' => 'bst','label'=>'State')); ?></li>
<li><div id="msg6"></div></li>
```

It is working when we select the country it load the states.

But what i want is once data has been saved, if user again visits that page i want the save data to be filled in the respective fields. only country field is displaying with the previously saved data, but not state field since i am loading state content in change event of the country.

Please help me come out from this problem because am new to php and cakephp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your state textbox name & db column name should be same here `bstate` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to the cake defaults for simplicity first. i.e.

```
<?php echo $form->input('bcountry'); ?>
```

If it auto populates, then the problem is in one of the options you specified in the optional array after 'bcountry'.

If it is still not working, then try debuging the output of $this->data to see if you really have access to the right information:

```
debug ($this->data);
```

If you don't see the information you are hoping to print out anywhere in that debug output, you have a problem in your model.